# Solr Direct Search Vs Oracle DB Text Field Direct Search

Tags: oracle, search, text, solr

I am working on a large scale oracle database. There is a requirement to validate whether the email address is available in the database when user enters it. If a direct database call is made it would be exact match 
e.g Select email from Users where emailaddress = "sampleemail@domain.com" it is not a LIKE. 
It has been suggested that rather than doing a direct database exact search it would be better to do a solr search for this. Even so it will be an exact match.

I would like understand, Can there be a significant advantage in using solr in this scenario as it is a exact match. If so how

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do that. Build an index in the database (a unique btree) and query that. Whoever suggested solr for this is highly misinformed about the trade offs. This is literally and exactly why there are indexes inside the database at all.